# Can't do an encryption on Lineage OS?

Tags: encryption, lineageos

I can't do an encryption on Lineage OS. When I start the encryption, my phone restarts. My device is Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: What version of Lineage is it? Possibly it was just built without encryption support.